# Can't find Scripting Bridge header files: mail.h iCal.h after upgrading Xcode

Tags: xcode, scripting-bridge

This should be easy..

I recently upgraded to the newest version of Xcode on 10.7 from Xcode 3.6 I believe.

I have been working with scripting bridge for both Apple Mail and iCal.

Previously, I could use FILE > Open Quickly... to view either the mail.h or iCal.h header files as entering the file name revealed only one file... the correct one.

Now, when I enter either mail.h or iCal.h using Open Quickly, dozens of files come up in the list, but NONE of them are the correct Scripting Bridge header files.

Can anyone tell me where and/or how to view these header files again?  It is driving me just a bit nuts here..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... solution found.

Aparently, the file no longer shows up as "mail.h" or "iCal.h" in the Open Quickly list.

It now shows up as "mail" or "iCal" but with a different icon than before.  The new icon shows as an underlined "C" in a brown square.

If you type the ".h" extension then it won't show up in the list at all.

Ugh.